# Trouble with testing menu with android:showAsAction using espresso

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-testing, android-menu, android-espresso

In my test case there is a place where in the sort button could be on the menu overflow or outside as I have used

> android:showAsAction=ifRoom

I test it on normal sized devices with onView(withId(R.id.sort)).perform(click()); 
but it fails on smaller screen devices. I read about

> openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());

on [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33990528/1349601) [[2]](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/advanced/#matching-a-view-that-is-inside-an-actionbar) but that fails as well.