# Espresso open bar

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

got the same problem as [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556883/how-to-click-on-action-bar-items-when-testing-with-android-espresso/)

but when i use

```
@Test
public void app6_7() throws Exception {
    onView(withId(R.id.email)).perform(clearText());
    onView(withId(R.id.email)).perform(typeText(userMail));
    onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(clearText());
    onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(typeText(userPassword));
    onView(withId(R.id.email_sign_in_button)).perform(click());
    openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
    onView(withContentDescription(R.id.drawerLayout)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.nav_logout)).perform(click());
```

i get this

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: ((is displayed on the screen to the user and with content description: is "More options") or (is displayed on the screen to the user and with class name: a string ending with "OverflowMenuButton"))
```

is the InstrumentationRegistry and getTargetContext not correct at this point ?
its my first time to espresso so maybe i overlooked something?

Comment: Filling login form and clicking sign in suggests, that some asynchronious operation is undergoing. Did you consider using `IdlingResources`?

Comment: fixed it yesterday with     open() but thx for the help